# Remove shape overlapping circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to remove the crossed out line in the image, i.e the top line of the rectangle, while keeping the circle intact.

Using merge remove the bottom half of the circle as well, which I dont want.

[image]

Comment: Use the [Shape Builder tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-shapes-shape-builder-tool.html).

Comment: No tool will really work because you use the inside stroke alignment and you need to have a open path lest you want conflation artefacts. Snapping to pixels is a lie one needs to be able to snap to half pixels.

Comment: no need to be negative, the shape builder tool isn't well known.

Comment: @joojaa if these are strokes, one could easily expand them to outlines before using the shape builder.

Comment: @BillyKerr at the expense of learning better ways and making it much harder to do changes later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a nice smooth merge, and keep the circle separate from the uprights:

1. Start out with your circle and rectangle as strokes with the **same line weight**.  <- This is important!

[image]

2. Use **Object** -> **Expand** -> **Stroke** *(uncheck Fill)* on JUST the rectangle.

[image]   [image]

You can then use the Snap feature to snap the center of the oval to the top of the rectangle which will give you a smooth edge. It will look like this when done:

[image]

3. Once aligned, use **Expand** -> **Stroke** again to outline the oval.

[image]

4. You now have your overlapping separate shapes ready for the Shape Builder Tool

[image]

5. Hold down the Option Key (Alt for PC I think) and click on the bar that you want to delete.  It will highlight the area that the tool will effect with a grey hash.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

6. To isolate the rectangle if you don't want the overlap, use the White+ arrow tool to select just the outer oval line.  Copy and Paste in front of everything, then select your rectangle and new oval together

[image]

7. Finally, using the Shape Builder Tool again holding down Option so it subtracts from the shape, click, or drag the mouse through the parts you want to delete, like so:

[image]

8. And the final product:

[image]